# Sendkeys not workining fine

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I'm trying to send username and password to gmail through sendkeys.But the problem is if i type sumanth as username here,in the gmail page it will come as ssuumanth and for password also same problem.
Please let me know where i'm wrong.
The image file contains the script.

Comment: If you need to script actions against websites, try a webclient or `InternetExplorer.Application` comobject. `SendKeys` is not a reliable solution from my experience. You could also try with a different browser to see if it helps. Check this ou for IE comobject tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337896.aspx

Comment: Why bother with a browser object and sendkeys? Gmail supports Imap, so mailbox can be accessed with a proper mail protocol.